# Unit testing with MVVM Light & DispatcherHelper

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, mvvm-light

I have a SL4 app that utilizes the MVVM Light Toolkit. Within a view model, I call a data service that retrieves data from an OData service. Within the VM, I am using the DispatcherHelper utility class (part of MVVM Light) to update the property on the VM from the data in the callback I pass into the data service. For instance, my view model method looks like this:

```
public string CurrentUserLogin {
  get {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentUserLogin))
      RetrieveCurrentUserLogin();
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentUserLogin) ? _currentUserLogin : _currentUserLogin.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
  }
  set {
    if (_currentUserLogin != value) {
      _currentUserLogin = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(CurrentUserLoginPropertyName);
    }
  }
}

private void RetrieveCurrentUserLogin() {
  DataService.GetCurrentUserLogin(result => {
    DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
      CurrentUserLogin = result;
    });
  });
}
```

And here's what my data service looks like:

```
public void GetCurrentUserLogin(Action<string> callback) {
  // create query request
  var query = OnDemandContext.CreateQuery<string>("GetCurrentUserLogin");
  var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(query.RequestUri);
  request.BeginGetResponse(asyncResult => {
    var responseStream = request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult).GetResponseStream();
    var responseDocument = XDocument.Load(responseStream);
    callback(responseDocument.Root.Value);
  }, null);
}
```

Everything works great when I run my SL application. However the problem I have is when I try to write unit tests against it using the SL Unit Testing Framework. I can test my data service without an issue, but it seems the DispatcherHelper is throwing a wrench into all my tests as the DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher is always null when fired. I'm assuming it has something to do with the initlization (which is in my SL app's Application_Startup()). I tried initializing it in my test app but that isn't helping. I've also tried using DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI() but that has no effect on the issue.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AC,

I just created a simple SL UT project and I did this in the App.XAML.CS

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  RootVisual = UnitTestSystem.CreateTestPage();
  DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
}
```

Then I set this as the test (in the tests.cs):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
   Assert.IsNotNull(DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher, "UI Dispatcher should not be null");

   DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
   {
       // Do nothing
       var x = 1;
   });
}
```

That worked for me. I even set a break point on the "var x = 1;" and it hit the breakpoint. Does this solve your problem? (if so please mark it as the answer).

Comment: Thanks DevTheo, your solution works, but that's not exactly the problem. The test project is testing the view model in another project. The DispatcherHelper is in the other project. The code snippet I have in my original question resides in the view model and I want to cover it in my unit test. I tried putting the DispatcherHelper.Initialize() in the test project, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'll give this another go.. but I gotta believe that if you get the DispatcherHelper Init'd in one of the projects it should work in both... maybe I'm wrong.. maybe it's attached to the App.. but the current app is the test project.. hmmm...

Comment: It should work because DispatcherHelper is storing the main thread's dispatcher statically. It sounds like you are indeed initializing the DispatcherHelper too late. Try to make sure that the Initialize method is called before the UIDispatcher property is used. Cheers.

Comment: So I went back and added the Initialize() call to my unit test immediately before I call the property on my view model that loads data in the getter that leverages the DispatcherHelper. When I step through it, I see it says that the UIDispatcher is no longer null... not sure what was wrong earlier. However I can't see if it is really fixed as my test is showing an exception was thrown, but was unhandled. Can't seem to track down where this is happening as it makes my test inconclusive... ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, my DispatchHelper wasn't working until I Initialized it.

Comment: SL UT is an unfortunate acronym for Silverlight Unit Test