# MVVM Light DispatcherHelper & Unit Testing w/MSTest

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm-light

I considered putting this as an additional question in this thread:

[Unit testing with MVVM Light & DispatcherHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716913/unit-testing-with-mvvm-light-dispatcherhelper)

but as I delved into it, I think it's a little different.

I have one project containing view models/views, a separate project containing models, and a third separate unit test project (MSTest) containing tests for the models.  I'm using MVVM Light's DispatcherHelper to help me do work in a background task, but to get errors from that task back to the UI.

The view model/view project has the App.xaml.cs file, which contains the OnStartup event handler, in which I've put the DispatcherHelper.Initialize() call.  One of the VMs invokes a call to one of the model's long-running methods on another thread using delegate.BeginInvoke():

```
     FileProcessDelegate processor = GenerateAddressingFile;
     processor.BeginInvoke(FileGenerationComplete, null);
```

In this long-running method, it calls a utility method to send errors back to the UI.  These are in the form of mvvm-light messages that are sent using the DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI()

```
    internal static void ReportErrorToUi(IFileError error)
    {
        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(
            () => Messenger.Default.Send(new GenericMessage<IFileError>(error), MessageTokens.ReportFileError));
    }
```

This all seems to work fine in the app.

In one of the unit test classes for the model, I attempt to check that the long-running method correctly sends messages when errors occur.  In that test class, I have a call to DispatcherHelper.Initialize() in the MSTest class initialization method.

```
    #region Additional test attributes
    // 
    //You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:
    //
    //Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
    }
```

The test registers for the message that should be sent, then calls the model's method directly, without invoking it on a separate thread.  As I understand it, because the call to send the message is wrapped by DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI() in the model, it  should do the right thing regardless of whether it is occurring on a background thread or on the UI thread.

In the first test of this class that checks the method, everything works fine.  The test receives the error messages being sent back and passes with flying colors.

When subsequent tests in the same class run, the messages are never received by the test.  When I've stepped through it on these subsequent tests, I notice that when I get to the  DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI() method, the DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.Thread instance says it's dead.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solution is something that can be included in Mvvm Light, or if it violates some base premises of the framework, but here's what I did to get this to work:

I made a custom local version of the DispatcherHelper class that has one minor difference from what's in Mvvm Light, namely the logic in the Initialize() method:

```
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        if (UIDispatcher != null &&
            UIDispatcher.Thread.IsAlive)
        {
            return;
        }
        UIDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    }
```

Here, the change is the addition of:

```
&& UIDispatcher.Thread.IsAlive
```

to the condition.  This allows me to call DispatcherHelper.Initialize() in the MyTestInitialize() method of my unit test class.  That way, if the previous thread that the UIDispatcher was associated with has died, the DispatcherHelper gets the new Dispatcher/Thread that this current test method will be run on.

Apparently, in the VSTS Testing framework, there is not a "central" thread that acts like the UI thread in an application.  The MyClassInitialize() method was executed on one thread, and then the tests were run on a completely different thread.  The Mvvm Light definition wouldn't let me hook the DispatcherHelper up to the new test thread by calling DispatcherHelper.Initialize() again because the UIDispatcher wasn't null, it's thread was just dead.

Answer (score 0):

Testing async code is tricky. Typically, if it works once, and then not anymore, it sounds like you are not synchronizing your threads correctly. In your test method (main thread), are you waiting for the background thread to execute?

Jonas Follesoe wrote a few good articles about async unit testing in Silverlight, for example http://jonas.follesoe.no/2007/09/18/unit-testing-event-based-asynchronous-code/. This is typically how I unit test my async code too.

Hope this helps,
Laurent

Comment: Thanks for the post Laurent; I'll check out the article.  I thought that in my unit test, since I make a direct call to the model's method, it is also running on the main thread.  And, since I use the DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI() call in the method I'm testing, it will work both in the unit test (same thread) and in the app (background thread).  Am I assuming correctly about how the DispatcherHelper works?

Comment: Further investigation makes me think that my problem is due to the MSTest model for execution.  The ClassInitialize() method where I init the DispatcherHelper runs on a particular thread, but then for each test method, a new instance of the test class is created, initialized, the method is run, and the class is cleaned up - all on a separate thread.  The initial thread that the DispatcherHelper was initialized on died as soon as the static ClassInitialize() method completed.